# How does curve_fit know which variables given in the model function correspond to the independent variable and which corresponds to parameters?

Tags: python, function, variables, scipy

I have a question about this script (written by someone else):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8
import sys
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def read_data(filename):
    data = np.loadtxt(filename)     
    return data[:,1], data[:,2] 
def eos_murnaghan(vol, E0, B0, BP, V0):
    return E0 + B0*vol/BP*(((V0/vol)**BP)/(BP-1)+1) - V0*B0/(BP-1)
def fit_murnaghan(volume, energy):
    # guess parameters with quadratic function
    p_coefs = np.polyfit(volume, energy, 2)
    p_min = - p_coefs[1]/(2.*p_coefs[0])
    # warn if min volume not in result range 
    if (p_min < volume.min() or p_min > volume.max()):
        print "Warning: minimum volume not in range of results"
    # estimate E0    
    E0 = np.polyval(p_coefs, p_min)
    # estimate B0
    B0 = 2.*p_coefs[2]*p_min
    # initial guesses of parameters
    init_par = [E0, B0, 4, p_min]
    print "guess parameters:"
    print " V0     =  {:1.4f} A^3 ".format(init_par[3])
    print " E0     =  {:1.4f} eV  ".format(init_par[0])
    print " B(V0)  =  {:1.4f} eV/A^3".format(init_par[1])
    print " B'(VO) =  {:1.4f} ".format(init_par[2])
    best_par, cov_matrix = curve_fit(eos_murnaghan, volume, energy, p0 = init_par)
    return best_par
def fit_and_plot(filename):
    # read data
    volume, energy = read_data(filename)   
    # fit parameters with Murnaghan
    best_par = fit_murnaghan(volume, energy)
    print "Fit parameters:"
    print " V0     =  {:1.4f} A^3 ".format(best_par[3])
    print " E0     =  {:1.4f} eV  ".format(best_par[0])
    print " B(V0)  =  {:1.4f} eV/A^3".format(best_par[1])
    print " B'(VO) =  {:1.4f} ".format(best_par[2])
    # fit Murnaghan model
    m_volume = np.linspace(volume.min(), volume.max(), 1000) 
    m_energy = eos_murnaghan(m_volume, *best_par) 
    # draw E-V
    lines = plt.plot(volume, energy, 'ok', m_volume, m_energy, '--r' )
    plt.xlabel(r"Volume [$\rm{A}^3$]")
    plt.ylabel(r"Energy [$\rm{eV}$]")
    return  best_par, lines
fit_and_plot("SUMMARY.dat")
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

My question is about the line:

```
best_par, cov_matrix = curve_fit(eos_murnaghan, volume, energy, p0 = init_par)
```

How does curve_fit determine which variables in eos_murnaghan does init_par, volume(xdata) and energy(ydata) correspond to?

Comment: for a start, the official docs, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Comment: )curve_fit args are `(f, xdata, ydata, p0)`.  you provide the same 4

Comment: Yeah. I mean how does curve_fit figure out how xdata, ydata and p0 corresponds to which of the variables in the expression E0 + B0*vol/BP*(((V0/vol)**BP)/(BP-1)+1) - V0*B0/(BP-1)

Comment: `ydata = func(xdata, p0,p1,p2,p3)`; `vol, E0, B0, BP, V0):` (I'd copy more but my phone is being fiddly)

Comment: So the order in which the p0 values are assigned is based on the order of parameters when I define the function?

Comment: Yes, the order should match across the p0 initial values, function call, and returned parameters. `  volume, E0, B0, 4, p_min]

Comment: Now I understand about it. Thanks!

Comment: @蕭力諶 If your question is answered then you can mark this post as closed.